# Google Cloud functions: When to use the exports object? And what role does index.js play?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In Google's [code lab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions#7), it says:

> Adding this function to the special exports object is Node's way of making the function accessible outside of the current file and is required for Cloud Functions.

What exactly does that mean? When do I need to add functions to the exports object?

And I'm not exactly sure what role `index.js` plays. Do I need to put all functions in there? What if I have let's say 3 different topics like `Posts`, `Messages`, and `Profiles`. Each topic has multiple cloud functions and many different simple helper functions (stuff like manipulating a string for example).

Should you really put all these functions in the same file then?

I think I don't really understand what `index.js` does.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase CLI will attempt to deploy any Cloud Functions exported from `index.js` only by default. That does not mean you have to write the whole code in the same file. You can create any directory structure of your own but just ensure the Cloud Functions are exported from `index.js`. For example:

```
// index.js
const processNewUser = require('./some/other/file.js');

exports.addWelcomeMessages = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  await processNewUser();
  return null;
});
```

Here the function `processNewUser()` is defined somewhere else but is called within the Cloud Function.

You can also define the Cloud Function itself for example:

```
// auth.js

const processNewUser = require('./some/other/file.js');

exports.addWelcomeMessages = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  await processNewUser();
  return null;
});
```

```
// index.js

const { addWelcomeMessages } = require("./auth.js")

exports.addWelcomeMessages;
```

If you do not add `exports.addWelcomeMessages;` (i.e. export the function from `index.js`, then the CLI won't deploy it.

Also checkout [organize multiple functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions) to learn about more possible cases.

Comment: Thanks. What about helper functions? They are not added to exports. So how are they added to the cloud?

Comment: @mathematics-and-caffeine they are not cloud functions right? If any cloud functions uses them, they'll be bundled together.